# How to count values in SQLITE in more then one column?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, sum, where-clause

I like to count the number of appearance of my users in more then one column. This is how I count the values in columns:

```
SELECT COUNT(col_01) FROM table_01 WHERE col_01 = 'John'     // result: 2
SELECT COUNT(col_02) FROM table_01 WHERE col_02 = 'John'     // result: 4
```

Is there any way to count John in one step in all columns I have and get the results 6?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter the table so that you get only the rows with 'John' in any of the 2 columns and then use aggregate function [`TOTAL()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) on each column:

```
SELECT TOTAL(col_01 = 'John') + TOTAL(col_02 = 'John') AS total
FROM table_01 
WHERE 'John' IN (col_01, col_02);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try *conditional aggregation*

```
select 
  sum(case when col_01='John' then 1 end) +
  sum(case when col_02='John' then 1 end)
from table_01;
```

Comment: You don't need the `case` expressions: In SQLite, `col_01='John'` and `col_01='John'` are already numeric expressions (with a value of 1 for true or 0 for false).

Comment: @dan04 `col_01='John'` and `col_02='John'` are numeric expressions 0 or 1 but on nullable columns they may also return `null` and if say col_01 is full of nulls the final result will be null. What is actually missing here is the `ELSE 0` part of the CASE expression.

Comment: I wouldn't normally use else 0 as NULLs are ignored by aggregates, but if there are no rows at all then yes `else 0` would make sense

Comment: *if there are no rows at all* or a column is full of nulls.